# Playing Bedrock on local user for Windows 10

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am looking to purchase Minecraft Bedrock Edition and it seems like Microsoft server CALs are easier to understand. My kid's account is a local account, not tied to a Microsoft account. Can I buy the Bedrock Edition and play it the same way as we use the Java version; logging in with an email or password? Can I buy it on my PC and then install it on his PC?

Answer (score 1):

So to buy Minecraft Windows 10 Editon or Bedrock you go here (https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/about-minecraft) and follow the instructions. Once you have bought it on Windows you can click on "Install on my Devices" and pick what device you want to install it on. If his computer does not pop up you may have to log in on your Microsoft account to download it.
(I am a bit inexperienced on Microsoft Store game sharing) It should download on his PC and the game should work fine. If you any more issues or questions feel free to comment on this thread.